# can you give an intuitive example of $X\bot (A\cap B)$ but not $X\bot A$ and not $X\bot B$?

Tags: probability, intuition

can you give an intuitive example of $X\bot (A\cap B)$ but not $X\bot A$ and not $X\bot B$ ?

Should be read as "X is [unconditionally independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) of $(A\cap B)$".

I'm looking for some real life example like the people getting home late in [Could someone explain conditional independence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23093/could-someone-explain-conditional-independence)

Comment: What does $\bot$ mean in the context of probabilities?

Comment: So "unconditionally independent" just means "independent"?

Comment: I don't know if this counts as a "real life" example but how about this: three balls are drawn, one by one without replacement, from an urn which initially contains two white balls and two black balls. The events are: A = "first ball is white", B = "second ball is black", X = "third ball is white".